# How do I configure canned responses in GMail so that it only sends the auto response to the original email and not to follow-up emails?

Tags: gmail-filters

The Company I work for deals with many customer enquiries and we rely a lot on email correspondence. I know how to create a canned response in GMail and am aware of its filters, but I was wondering if there's a way for the canned response to only be sent out to the original email enquiry and NOT the consequent follow-up emails (this would get annoying for the receiver!).

E.g. Whenever let's say an email comes from `abc@gmail.com` we can trigger the canned response to get sent, but if that same email address is replying to add to his/her enquiry, then that same canned response would no longer be appropriate.

Is there a way for GMail to track follow-up emails for canned responses?

Answer (score 1):

Include an additional filter criteria to exclude messages where the subject contains (or starts with )  "Re:"?